# Fetching .zip files from database

Tags: python, oracle, file

I have a database which contains my released project in.zip format, so the problem here is that, after certain period of time , i have to download those .zip files from my db and mail it to customers. Its a manual process.So is there any way/framework available in python that can automate this process? Any leads suggestion will be very helpful. I can handle the sending mail part ,the main thing  i have to ask to automate the process of fetching files from db.

Comment: Please have a look at the [guidelines for How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question on Stack Overflow. This really isn't the place for general questions, as the [on-topic guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) state: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." We can help when you've given this a try yourself, and have a specific question!

Comment: Are these literally .zip files stored on a filesystem on a database, or are they ZIP files stored in a BLOB column in a table?

Comment: Hi Jon, They are zip file stored in blob column